# How to put specific category posts on specific pages in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, categories

I purchased the Primashop theme. Now I want to show posts that have, let's say a category ID of 25. Category 25 I want to show on let's say the About page. Posts created in category ID 40 I want to show on the Contact page.

I've searched on Google and many sites, but there ain't a proper tutorial. In the theme I can have different page templates. So I've created a page_about.php file template. In there I've placed the following code:

```
<?php 

query_posts( 'category_id = 25' );

if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  echo '<li>';

     the_title();

echo '</li>';

endwhile; 

wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

What it does is it shows all the posts in a list. Not from only category 25. Also I not only want to display the title, but also the excerpt and image. How to make a proper list? Is it that hard to do??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read wordpress codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

You should use cat=25 instead of category_id=25.

To display excerpt and the image, you'd want functions like:

- the_post_thumbnail() - for image
- the_excerpt() - for excerpt

Also, consider whether you really need to embed this in a template. Maybe plugin with shortcode (e.g. http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/) would be enough for you?